# Laravel 4 custom validation rule - where to extend the validator?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to make a custom validation rule.
My model looks like this at the moment:

```
protected $rules = array(
    'first_name'  => 'required',
    'last_name'   => 'required',
    'ssn'         => 'required|integer|min:4|max:4',
    'email'       => 'required|email',
    'dob'         => 'required|checkAge',
    'phone'       => 'required',
    'street'      => 'required',
    'postal_code' => 'required|integer|min:4',
    'city'        => 'required'
);
```

But where I have to put the custom validation rule?
I have read that I need to extend it Validator.
For this I've created a simple function

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value == 'foo';
});
```

And I don't know where I have to check it?

Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Where should we put in it in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do it by creating a validation folder in /app with any custom validation files in there.
I autoload this by editing **app/start/global.php**.

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path() . '/commands',
    app_path() . '/controllers',
    app_path() . '/models',
    app_path() . '/presenters',
    app_path() . '/validation',
    app_path() . '/database/seeds',
));
```

I also register the resolver in this file;

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
        return new CoreValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    });
```

A sample custom validator class (in the validation folder);

```
<?php

class CoreValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{

    protected $implicitRules = array('Required', 'RequiredWith', 'RequiredWithout', 'RequiredIf', 'Accepted', 'RequiredWithoutField');

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        $this->isImplicit('fail');
    }

    public function validatePostcode($attribute, $value, $parameters = null)
    {
        $regex = "/^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$/i";
        if (preg_match($regex, $value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And add the custom error message to the array in in **app/lang/en/validation.php**

```
return array(
...
"postcode" => "Invalid :attribute entered.",
...
)
```

Comment: I also created a validation folder like that where I like to put all my validation stuff. I like to seperate validation from my models because that feels sloppy

Answer (score 8):

Extensions can be added as soon as the application boots. What I do is to create a `validations.php` file in the same level of `routes.php` and `filters.php` and then add this to my `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/filters.php'; /// this one is already there...
require app_path().'/validations.php';
```